# Chai.js: Object contains/includes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, tdd, chai

[Chai](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) has an `include` method. I want to test to see if an object contains another object. For example:

```
var origin = {
  name: "John",
  otherObj: {
    title: "Example"
  }
}
```

I want to use Chai to test if this object contains the following (which it does)

```
var match = {
  otherObj: {
    title: "Example"
  }
}
```

Doing this does not appear to work:

```
origin.should.include(match)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The include and contain assertions can be used as **either** property based language chains **or** as methods to assert the inclusion of an object in an **array** or a substring in a **string**. When used as language chains, they toggle the contain flag for the keys assertion.  [emphasis mine]

So if you're invoking include on an object (not an array or a string), then it only serves to toggle the contain flag for the keys assertion. By the looks of your example, testing for deep equality would make more sense, possibly checking for the key first.

```
origins.should.include.keys("otherObj");
origins.otherObj.should.deep.equal(match.otherObj);
```

Actually, now I browse the other examples, you would probably be happiest with this :

```
origins.should.have.deep.property("otherObj", match.otherObj)
```

Comment: I did read the docs, but sometimes you need a bit more context, you know? Thanks for this answer.

Comment: That's true, I didn't intend to be mean about it. It's just that the docs for chai are actually quite excellent compared to most docs I encounter (they include examples and everything! =P). I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 34):

Hei, just published chai-subset. Check this out: https://www.npmjs.org/package/chai-subset
This should work for you)

```
 var chai = require('chai');
 var chaiSubset = require('chai-subset');
 chai.use(chaiSubset);

 var obj = {
     a: 'b',
     c: 'd',
     e: {
         foo: 'bar',
         baz: {
             qux: 'quux'
         }
     }
 };

 expect(obj).to.containSubset({
     e: {
         foo: 'bar',
         baz: {
             qux: 'quux'
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Nice plugin, but this answer should include an usage example, otherwise you may be flagged.

Comment: would b great if it will tell exactly which property is failing an assertion

Comment: @AdamGoldman Feel free to create issue or even PR in github repo

Answer (score 12):

In chai 4.2.0, for example you can use deep include

chaijs doc examples:

```
// Target array deeply (but not strictly) includes `{a: 1}`
expect([{a: 1}]).to.deep.include({a: 1});
expect([{a: 1}]).to.not.include({a: 1});

// Target object deeply (but not strictly) includes `x: {a: 1}`
expect({x: {a: 1}}).to.deep.include({x: {a: 1}});
expect({x: {a: 1}}).to.not.include({x: {a: 1}});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you know the level of the subobject you can simply use:

```
expect(origin.otherObj).to.include(match.otherObj);
```

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/

Answer (score -4):

In Chai 1.5.0 you will find handy method

```
includeDeepMembers
```

http://chaijs.com/releases/

Comment: I upvoted this but its actually wrong. includeDeepMembers only works on arrays, not objects.